# How to get object's world rotation around z axis

Tags: python

I have an empty as a parent for a sphere. I need to get the sphere's rotation around the z-axis relative to the world matrix.

I've tried the following:

```py
matrix = bpy.data.objects['E' + str(i).zfill(1)].matrix_world
e = np.degrees(np.array(matrix.to_euler('XYZ')[0:3]))
print('Yaw %.2f Pitch %.2f Roll %.2f' % (e[2], e[1], e[0]))
```

but none of the values seems to make sense.

Comment: which one of empty and sphere is `bpy.data.objects['E' + str(i).zfill(1)]`

Comment: and can you please elaborate on result seen, and expected result.  An issue could be that blender by default uses -Y as forward which would infer pitching about X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, or even an example of your output, I'm assuming the result does not make sense because they are displayed in radians. Blender uses radians at it's core so all raw rotational data is in radians.

To get the Z rotation of an object, use `import mathutils` and to convert to degrees from radians, use `import math`

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import math

matrix = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].matrix_world # assign Cube matrix
eul = mathutils.Euler(matrix.to_euler('XYZ'), 'XYZ') # create an Euler from the matrix using mathutils
print (math.degrees(eul.z)) # print the Z value from the Euler converted to degrees via math
```

Comment: `np.degrees()` as used in question code, converts to degrees.

Comment: numpy huh? That's a new one to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have seems correct, and you are probably getting a numpy array value such as:

```
array([ 6.83018998e-06, -0.00000000e+00, -4.49564076e+01])
```

Here the values are represented in scientific notation. You can use these values as it is in your program but if you want the readable degrees you can calculate the values by;

$$ (X, Y, Z) = (6.83018998 * 10^{-06}, 0*10^{0}, -4.49564076 * 10^{1}) \approx (0, 0, -44.9)$$